# Locke - A return to nature

Tags: locke

In Locke's treatises, does he discuss/explore leaving a government as an individual  as opposed to a revolution of the people and returning to a state of nature if one does not agree to abide by the majority?

Comment: What has your research shown so far? Welcome to philosophy.SE!

Comment: Thanks.  Aside from a revolution, which isn't exactly what I'm talking about, more of an individual secession, I didn't find anything explicit.  But I'm not well read on the subject.  Just starting to learn :)

Comment: There are some excellent scholars here. Have you searched philosophy.SE for "Locke"?

Comment: I searched Locke and state of nature.  Didn't find an answer.